# the framework is react,, the question is how can I upload (an image or pdf) when clicking on it, in the nutria of the <img> and <div> tags

Tags: reactjs

The problem is that my code works but when downloading it says that the file type is not supported
by my code --->

```
var urlContract = "https://dashboard-8tl3.onrender.com/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_2024-03-11_144401.png"

 function downloadContract(urlContract) {
    if (urlContract.includes("png")) {
        const blob = new Blob([urlContract], { type: "image/png" });
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", URL.createObjectURL(blob));
        link.setAttribute("download", "Contract.png");
        link.click();
      }
      if (urlContract.includes("jpeg")) {
        const blob = new Blob([urlContract], { type: "image/jpeg" });
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", URL.createObjectURL(blob));
        link.setAttribute("download", "Contract.jpeg");
        link.click();
      }
      if (urlContract.includes("pdf")) {
        const blob = new Blob([urlContract], { type: "application/pdf" });
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", URL.createObjectURL(blob));
        link.setAttribute("download", "Contract.pdf");
        link.click();
      }
```

Comment: There are several issues. (1) Use `.endsWith(".pdf“)` instead of your .include's, because now there could be multiple if-blocks that run after one another. Also best to use `else if` instead of just `if` for all but the first. (2) The **download** attribute is "boolean", if it is present it means `true` and if not present then it means `false`. Putting a filename in it will have no effect whatsoever.